# Why a string surrounded with single quotes will not interpolate the variable names it contains in PHP, while with double quotes it does?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Difference between single quote and double quote string in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/difference-between-single-quote-and-double-quote-string-in-php)

We can include the name of a variable right inside a text string and have the value inserted in its place if we surround the string with double quotes instead of single quotes.

why does not it works in case of single quotes?

Comment: Because that's how it's meant to be. See [Difference between single quote and double quote string in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/difference-between-single-quote-and-double-quote-string-in-php)

Comment: That's how it is: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is exactly the intended difference between single and double quotes, the double are used when something might need to be replaced by the interpreter, and single quotes tells php that the string will be as is..