# trouble passing php variable into mysql string

Tags: php, mysql

I have been trying to get this for hours, and I know there are other topics similar to this but I'm still stuck... basically I'm trying to list all the customers with last names that start with the letter A:

I'm passing a variable called lname in the URL like this:

Then I grab the variable in the PHP like:

```
$lname = $_GET['lname'];
$lname = mysql_real_escape_string($lname);

// HERE'S THE PROBLEM AREA:  then I try to put a simple query together like this:

$query = 'SELECT * FROM customers WHERE customers.lname LIKE "$lname%"';

// then I want to make sure $query and $lname have values in them, so I echo them out:

echo $query;
echo ' $lname = '.$lname;

// and the output is:

SELECT * FROM customers WHERE customers.lname LIKE "$lname%" 
$lname = A
Unknown column '$lname' in 'where clause'
```

So you can see that in the query, after the LIKE, it should say LIKE 'A', but it is parsing to LIKE $lname.   I've tried all kinds of variations such as:

$query = 'SELECT * FROM customers WHERE customers.lname LIKE ".$lname."';
$query = 'SELECT * FROM customers WHERE customers.lname LIKE {$lname}%';
etc, etc, etc

Strange, but the column lname is DEFINITELY there in the customers table, and so I'mk not sure why it's reporting that error of 'Unknown column '$lname' in 'where clause''

And for the record, when I manually just change the query to include the value I want, it outputs the list of customer names perfectly:

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM customers WHERE customers.lname LIKE "A%"';
```

... so the query works, but I can't get the $lname to be interpolated.

THANK YOU for any help. How can I get that variable $lname to pass the VALUE that's inside of $lname in my mysql query?

Comment: Variables aren't interpolated in single quoted strings.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why a string surrounded with single quotes will not interpolate the variable names it contains in PHP, while with double quotes it does?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14338059/why-a-string-surrounded-with-single-quotes-will-not-interpolate-the-variable-nam)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$query = "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE customers.lname LIKE '$lname%'";

Interchange your single quotes and double quotes in the above line.

Comment: THANKS man!! Gosh I tried so many variations. It works! I didn't know interchanging the quotes would have that effect but THANKS!! Peace!

Answer (score 1):

You should really think about using parameterized queries.  For instance,

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE customers.lname LIKE ?";
$stm = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stm->execute(array($lname));
```

This would help with many problems you are likely experiencing, and is much more secure.

Comment: Brian thank you!  Great point there. I am, as you can prob tell, a novice coder, so I need to get up to speed on those security methods. Thank you for the help!